# firebase getting a document from within a cloud function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a cloud function which attempts to add a "follower" to a users followers collection which will store this data:

id
username
timestamp

The username property isn't available so I need to get the user doc from firestore and store the username property value so I can add it when I create the new document in the users->following collection.

I've tried several different ways of getting the document but no matter what I try, I keep bumping into some promise related errors.

The current iteration of my function looks like this:

```
exports.onFollowCreate = functions.firestore
    .document('users/{user_id}/{following}/{id}')
    .onCreate((snap, context) => {
      const newValue = snap.data();
      const db = admin.firestore();
      db.collection("users")
          .doc(context.params.user_id)
          .update({followingCount: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)})
          .catch((er) => {
            console.log(er);
          });

      const userDocRef = admin.firestore().collection("users").doc(context.params.id);
      userDocRef.get().then((snapshot) => {
        if (snapshot.docs.length > 0) {
          snapshot.docs.foreach((doc) => {
            const username = doc.data();

            db.collection("users")
                .doc(newValue.id)
                .collection("followers")
                .doc(context.params.user_id)
                .set({
                  id: context.params.user_id,
                  username: username,
                  timeStamp: new Date(),
                })
                .catch((er) => console.log(er));
          });
        } else {
          console.log("Error: No documents found");
        }
      });
    });
```

Showing the following in the google cloud functions logs explorer:

```
Function execution started
Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value
Function execution took 3179 ms. Finished with status: ok
Exception from a finished function: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you got error is because in the line:

```
 const userDocRef = admin.firestore().collection("users").doc(context.params.id);
```

The `userDocRef` will get exactly one doc. Instead of reaching it in the `docs`, you should check the document existence by `snapshot.exists()`. The `docs` field doesn't exist here, so `snapshot.docs.length` is throwing an error.

Besides of that, the code has multiple places to change:

1. Despite we don't need to use `foreach` at all, you don't need to wrap a pure foreach loop in a if statement.
2. If my understanding is right, the `username` is a string, but you will get a json file from `snapshot.data()`. Consider change the code to
   `const username = doc.data()["username"];`

Comment: Thank you so Much Fang. What you suggested worked but instead of snapshot.exists() I had to use !snapshot.empty